# In which layer should I make network calls when implementing MVP?

Tags: android

I have searched about this a lot but I haven't found anything about it. Suppose I want to authenticate an user by sending an username and password to the server. In which layer should I make the appropriate network calls and why? Should this be done in the Presentation layer or the Model layer?

Comment: IMO it should be on the Model layer, while the validation should happen on Presenter.

Comment: Suppose i am using volley for making network call, where does the code for it goes ? should i create a function inside the model class or in presentation layer?

Comment: Your Volley framework is already your Model. You are just going to call it in your presenter and fulfill its arguments by your validated inputs.

Comment: So would it be right by the MVP policy if I make my network calls from presenter layer and fetch data(JSON in my case) and store it using the interface provided my the model layer?

Answer (score 1):

Login logic is a Model responsability, it's used to set up model state. After logging in you'll probably have an authorized user with a related model that you will use on lower layers to present views.

Comment: OK i get it!
I have one more doubt, the next step will be fetching data from network, add then fetching details for each item. What about make a class alongside all Model classes that helps in fetching data from network

Comment: @GurleenSethi: definitively it would be wise to encapsulate common logic to access remote data store.